# Trying to upgrade TypeScript but old version still not uninstalling / being replaced

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to upgrade TypeScript from 3.4.5 to 4.5.4 having migrated a NativeScript project from version 6.5.0 to 8.1.5.

Ideally to completely remove the old TypeScript 3.4.5 but it still seems to be there. I have checked the other similar queries like this one but have not been able to get rid of it. I do not have Visual Studio installed.

Am using nvm and am currently on node 16.10.0 and npm 7.24.0

My package.json has `"typescript": "^4.5.4",` in the dependencies. Here is the whole package.json.

```
{
  "description": "Reports App | Mobile Expense Reports",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"app/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "8.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.1",
    "@master.technology/permissions": "~2.0.1",
    "@nativescript-community/ui-material-bottom-navigation": "^6.2.11",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~13.0.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/fingerprint-auth": "8.0.0",
    "nativescript-app-sync": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-bottom-navigation": "^2.0.5",
    "nativescript-camera": "^4.5.0",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "^6.0.1",
    "nativescript-fancyalert": "~3.1.1",
    "nativescript-fingerprint-auth": "~7.0.2",
    "nativescript-fontawesome": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-gradient": "^2.0.1",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "~7.1.0",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-modal-datetimepicker": "~2.1.5",
    "nativescript-pdf-view": "^3.0.0-1",
    "nativescript-permissions": "~1.3.12",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~2.0.24",
    "nativescript-toast": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "~10.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
    "ruby": "^0.6.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.1",
    "@nativescript/android": "~8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~13.1.1",
    "@types/node": "14.6.2",
    "babel-traverse": "6.26.0",
    "babel-types": "6.26.0",
    "babylon": "6.18.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~3.0.2",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "sass": "~1.39.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "main": "main.js"
}
```

I have tried many things like

```
npm uninstall -g typescript
```

```
npm install -g typescript
```

```
ns clean
```

```
npm install
```

And I still get

```
$ tsc -v
Version 3.4.5
```

I cannot see where it is pulling it from.

ng --version gives:

```
Angular CLI: 13.2.2
Node: 16.10.0
Package Manager: npm 7.24.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.1.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1301.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.1.4
@angular-devkit/core            13.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.2.2 (cli-only)
@angular/http                   8.0.0-beta.10+1.sha-a28b3e3
@ngtools/webpack                13.1.4
@schematics/angular             13.2.2 (cli-only)
rxjs                            7.4.0
typescript                      4.5.4
```

I also tried deleting node_modules, hooks and platforms and reinstalling but tsc still gives v3.4.5.

Can you see what version I am on?

========
UPDATE

I did it (in Windows) by deleting the

`C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript`

folder
and replacing it with the

`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\typescript`

folder.

I think when running

`npm i -g typescript`
NVM was saving it to

`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules`

and

`C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.10.0\node_modules`

but not

`C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

Comment: Is there a particular reason to install it globally? Most systems (including TypeScript) don't recommend doing that nowadays. Part of the problem is that `tsc` is different from `npx tsc` in your case. See [Download TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/download)

Comment: Hi @crashmstr when I do ````npm i typescript --save-dev```` it goes into the project node_modules but ````tsc -v```` doesn't see it. I get 

````node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc'
...
/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'',
  requireStack: []
}
````

Comment: You use `npx tsc -v` to reference the project installed version. This also allows different project to work with different versions. This is how almost all npm packages are set up for now instead of installing globally.

Comment: If you look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/download, `npx tsc` is what is shown on the TypeScript site.